# Trying to find the index of the column name called `Customers' inside a table result -1

Tags: javascript, cypress

Trying to find the index of the column name called `Customers` inside a table using jQuery/javascript, but this is always giving me `-1`

```
let tableDatacy = "Results_Table";
let columnName = "Customer";
let tableHeaders = [];
tableHeaders = Cypress.$(`[data-cy=${tableDatacy}] > thead:nth-child(0) > tr:contains(${columnName})`);
let columnPosition = tableHeaders.toString().indexOf(columnName);
```

```html
 <table data-cy="Results_Table">
   <thead class="HeaderOriginal">
    <tr class="tablesorter-headerRow">
    <th class="hideExport hidePrint tablesorter-header" data-column="0" tabindex="0" unselectable="on" style="user-select: none;"><div class="tablesorter-header-inner">&nbsp;</div></th>
  <th class="ajaxOrder tablesorter-header" order="customer" data-column="3" tabindex="0" unselectable="on" style="user-select: none;">
       <div class="tablesorter-header-inner">
       <a href="javascript: void(0);" class="desc">Customers</a>
       </div>
   </th>
   <th class="hideExport" data-column="0" tabindex="0" unselectable="on" style="user-select: none;"><div class="tablesorter-header-inner">&nbsp;</div></th>
  <th class="ajaxOrder tablesorter-header" order="customer" data-column="3" tabindex="0" unselectable="on" style="user-select: none;">
       <div class="tablesorter-header-inner">
       <a href="javascript: void(0);" class="desc">Machine</a>
       </div>
   </th>
   </tr>
   </thead>
 </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to use jQuery, the equivalent would be

```js
const index = Cypress.$(`[data-cy="Results_Table"]`)
  .find(`th:has(a:contains("Customers"))`)
  .index()
```

**Note:** the page should be loaded before attempting to use jQuery, e.g

```js
beforeEach(() => {
  cy.visit(...)
})

it('...', () => {

  const index = Cypress.$(`[data-cy="Results_Table"]`)
    .find(`th:has(a:contains("Customers"))`)
    .index()
  ...
})
```

Comment: `.find('th:contains('Customers')')` should be `.find('th:has(a:contains('Customers'))`) because jQuery contains() only looks a the current element text.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `invoke('index')`to invoke the index value of your columns. You read more about it from the [Jquery Docs](https://api.jquery.com/index/).

```
cy.get('[data-cy="Results_Table"]')
    .find(`th:contains('Customers')`)
    .invoke('index')
    .then((index) => {
        cy.log(index); // Will Print 1
    });
```

In case you want to use the index value later in the same test, you can use `.as()`

```
cy.get('[data-cy="Results_Table"]')
    .find(`th:contains('Customers')`)
    .invoke('index')
    .as('indexValue')

cy.get('@indexValue').then((indexValue) => {
    expect(indexValue).to.eq(1)
    //Use the index value here
})
```

Comment: Thank you Alapan Das, In this approach I need to write rest of the code inside cypress promise part, later the scope index will be a problem..

Comment: I have updated my answer. You can use `.as()` aliases to access the values later in the same test. One thing to remember is that cypress resets all aliases before each test.